# Django Ajax 'GET' return only strings

Tags: jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get some data from my database using ajax, and iterate it.
for some reason, I get a long string, and not object that I can iterate.

**views.py**

```
def postHog(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    pk = request.GET['megama']
    megama = Speciality.objects.get(id=pk)
    hog = Submain.objects.filter(speciality=megama)
    hogback = []
    for i in hog:
        if (i.image):
            hogback.append({"name": i.name, "desc": 
            i.desc, "image": i.image.url})
        else:
            hogback.append({"name": i.name, "desc": i.desc, "image": "None"})
response_data=json.dumps(hogback,ensure_ascii=False)
return JsonResponse({'hogback': response_data}, status=200,content_type="application/json")
```

**urls.py**

```
path(r'megamas/', views.postHog, name="post_hog"),
```

**myjs.js**

```
 $(".btnsmain").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/megamas",
        data:{
            megama:$("#id_main").val()
        },
        success:function (data) {

            $.each(data.hogback, function (index,element) {
                alert(index,element.name);

            });

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("not good");

        }
    })
});
```

if i use alert(hogback[0]) i get the "["
its like i am getting back strings and not the list and dict objects.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps()` returns a json-formatted string.

`JsonResponse` takes `data` as a python object, so you don't need to manually convert your data into json. (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects))

So the following should work:

```py
return JsonResponse({'hogback': hogback}, status=200, content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just You Need to parse method of javascript **JSON.parse**, which identify string and then convert in JSON object

> You need edit you success method off ajax like this

```
        success:function (data) {
           const jsonData = JSON.parse(data)
           alert(jsonData)
           console.log(jsonData[0])
        },
```

May Be You understand what i said also i gave link see them 
- [enter link description here](https://alligator.io/js/json-parse-stringify/)

If your problem solve then let me know